# Can't write frames to a video with multiprocessing + cv2

Tags: python, opencv, video, multiprocessing

I have a code which breaks down a video into frames and edits the image and puts it back into a video, but I am realizing that it's really slow... So I looked into multiprocessing for speeding up the code, and it works! As I can see it processes the images much faster, but the problem is, when I add those frames to a new video, it doesn't work, the video remains empty!

Here is my code:

```
# Imports
import cv2, sys, time
import numpy as np

from scipy.ndimage import rotate
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageOps
import concurrent.futures
def function(fullimg):
    img = np.array(Image.fromarray(fullimg).crop((1700, 930, 1920-60, 1080-80)))
    inpaintRadius = 10
    inpaintMethod = cv2.INPAINT_TELEA
    textMask = cv2.imread('permanentmask.jpg', 0)
    final_result = cv2.inpaint(img.copy(), textMask, inpaintRadius, inpaintMethod)
    text = Image.fromarray(np.array([np.array(i) for i in final_result]).astype(np.uint8)).convert('RGBA')
    im = np.array([[tuple(x) for x in i] for i in np.zeros((70, 160, 4))])
    im[1:-1, 1:-1] = (170, 13, 5, 40)
    im[0, :] = (0,0,0,128)
    im[1:-1, [0, -1]] = (0,0,0,128)
    im[-1, :] = (0,0,0,128)
    im = Image.fromarray(im.astype(np.uint8))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arialbd.ttf', 57)
    draw.text((5, 5),"TEXT",(255,255, 255, 128),font=font)
    text.paste(im, mask=im)
    text = np.array(text)
    fullimg = Image.fromarray(fullimg)
    fullimg.paste(Image.fromarray(text), (1700, 930, 1920-60, 1080-80))
    fullimg = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(fullimg), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return fullimg
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('before2.mp4')
_fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('after.mp4', _fourcc, 29.97, (1280,720))
frames = []
lst = []
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, fullimg = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    frames.append(fullimg)
    
    if len(frames) >= 8:
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                results = executor.map(function, frames)
                for i in results:
                    print(type(i))
                    out.write(i)
        frames.clear() 
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # destroy all opened windows
```

My code inpaints a watermark and adds another watermark using PIL.

If I don't use `multiprocessing` the code works. But if I do use `multiprocessing`, it gives an empty video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that familiar with `OpenCV`, but there seems to be a few things that should be corrected in your code. First, if you are running under Windows, as you appear to be because you have `if __name__ == '__main__':` guarding the code that creates new processes (by the way, when you tag a question with `multiprocessing`, you should also tag the question with the platform being used), then any code at global scope will be executed by every process created to implement your pool. That means you should move `if __name__ == '__main__':` as follows:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('before2.mp4')
    _fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('after.mp4', _fourcc, 29.97, (1280,720))
    frames = []
    lst = []
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, fullimg = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frames.append(fullimg)
        
        if len(frames) >= 8:
            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                results = executor.map(function, frames)
                for i in results:
                    print(type(i))
                    out.write(i)
            frames.clear() 
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() # destroy all opened windows
```

If you do not do this it seems to me that every sub-process in the pool will first attempt in parallel to create an empty video (the `function` worker function and `out.write` will never be called by these processes) and only then will the main process be able to invoke the `function` worker function using `map`. This doesn't quite explain why the main process doesn't succeed after all of these wasteful attempts. But...

You also have:

```py
while cap.isOpened():
```

The documentations states that `isOpened()` returns `True` if the previous `VideoCapture` constructor succeeded. Then if this returns `True` once, why wouldn't it return `True` the next time it is tested and you end up looping indefinitely? Shouldn't the `while` be changed to an `if`? And doesn't this suggest that `isOpened()` is perhaps returning `False` or else you would be looping indefinitely? Or what if `len(frames) < 8`? It seems then you would also end up with an empty output file.

My suggestion would be to make the above changes and try again.

**Update**

I took a closer look at the code more closely and it appears that it is looping reading the input (**before2.mp4**) one frame at a time and when it has accumulated 8 frames or more it creates a pool and processes the frames it has accumulated and writing them out to the output (**after.mp4**). But that means that if there are, for example, 8 more frames, it will create a brand new processing pool (very wasteful and expensive) and then write out the 8 additional processed frames. But if there were only 7 additional frames, they would never get processed and written out. I would suggest the following code (untested, of course):

```py
def main():
    import os

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('before2.mp4')
    if not cap.isOpened():
        return

    _fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('after.mp4', _fourcc, 29.97, (1280,720))

    FRAMES_AT_A_TIME = 8
    pool_size = min(FRAMES_AT_A_TIME, os.cpu_count())
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=pool_size) as executor:
        more_frames = True

        while more_frames:
            frames = []
            for _ in range(FRAMES_AT_A_TIME):
                ret, fullimg = cap.read()
                if not ret:
                    more_frames = False
                    break
                frames.append(fullimg)

            if not frames:
                break # no frames        

            results = executor.map(function, frames)
            for i in results:
                print(type(i))
                out.write(i)

    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() # destroy all opened windows

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: For my edification, which of all the suggestions did you incorporate?

Comment: Moving `if __name__ == '__main__'` solved it

Comment: Then am I correct in inferring that following `cap.read()` that `cap.isOpened()` is no longer `True`? Otherwise, I can't see why you do not loop indefinitely.

Comment: Possibly. I am not so familiar with multiprocessing and cv2.

Comment: I've looked at the code again and think I understand it better and believe there is a problem with it performance and correctness-wise. I have a suggested update (use at your own risk, of course, but for you to look at).

Comment: Depending on how large frames are, you might also wish to increase `FRAMES_AT_A_TIME`.

Comment: Great thanks! It's great! I am now also using multithreading, realized thread pools for some reason are much much faster!

Comment: 1. There is a lot of overhead in creating processes under Windows. 2. What is normally a problem with multithreading is that Python bytecode cannot run in parallel because they lock the Global Interpreter Lock. But this is not a problem when either the code spends a lot of time in C-language code (`cv2`? and `numpy`) or is waiting for I/O, such as reading and writing frames.

Comment: Yeap! Will look into it